# How call a callback of an Ajax function in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function which is loading data from a webservice. It looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: back + this.path_Uri,
    data: {msg:this.msg},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, statut) {
                        // traitement to not execute here
        window.reloadFreelancersMission= data;
        var number = reloadFreelancersMission.pagination[0].pagenbr;
        window.pagination.ReloadPager(number);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I need to do some treatment in the result of the response of this web service in another function in another file.

My file contains a function of sending data within my ajax function. It looks like this

```
sendFiltres: function () {
    $("body").on('change', '.filtres' , function () {
        var choix_filtres = $("#fitre_recherche");
        var msgJson = JSON.stringify(serializeObject($("#fitre_recherche")));
        window.sendData.start(choix_filtres,msgJson);
    })
},
```

So I need here to use the callback of my function in this way:

```
request.done(function( msg ) {
    console.log( msg );
});
```

and integrate my treatment, to obtain this for:

```
request.done(function( msg ) {
    window.reloadFreelancersMission= data;
    var number = reloadFreelancersMission.pagination[0].pagenbr;
    window.pagination.ReloadPager(number);
});
```

but it seems that I can't call this callback in this file. I'm allowed to use it only in the same file of my ajax function, and that's exactly my problem.

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Are you trying to load a file at `success` of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @maladin ; try to learn more about ajax

Comment: yes i am trying to recuper data from success.java in another function in another js.file

Comment: @firasKoubaa Try using `$.getScript()` to request file at `success` of `$.ajax()`

Comment: yeah it can do the job , in my case i have used  "ajaxSuccess" of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I resolved my problem by recuperating the response of my service within the callback function of jQuery `ajaxSuccess`

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === window.find_mission.route.getmission || settings.url === window.find_freelance.route.getfreelance) {
        xhr = xhr.responseJSON;
        var pagenumber = xhr.pagination[0].pagenbr;
        window.pagination.ReloadPager(pagenumber);
     }
 });
```

where I was using the `xhr` variable to get my data.